# How to get WKT or GEOJson by country or city name with Overpass API?

Tags: openstreetmap, polygon, geojson, overpass-api

I'm trying to understand Overpass API, I'm experimenting with it, but cannot get what I expect. Overpass API doesn't return me neither polygon shapes, nor WKT, nor GEOJson, nor even a highlight of the area I'm querying for.

My goal is to get either WKT or GEOJson of current OSM relations (exactly polygons (a set of lng/lat points)) for countries and cities. For example, I want to get a polygon for France. I make these queries in http://overpass-turbo.eu/:

```
relation
    ["name"="France"]
    ["coverage"="polygon"]
    ["type"="boundary:administrative"];
out body;
```

The response I get, no any polygon lat/lng data:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note>
<meta osm_base="2013-11-08T11:43:01Z"/>


</osm>
```

The second version of my request, I provide only a name:

```
relation
    ["name"="France"];
out body;
```

Now I get dilated information about the country, but no polygons either:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<osm version="0.6" generator="Overpass API">
<note>The data included in this document is from www.openstreetmap.org. The data is made available under ODbL.</note>
<meta osm_base="2013-11-08T11:37:02Z"/>

  <relation id="11980">
    <member type="node" ref="17807753" role="admin_centre"/>
    <member type="relation" ref="1362232" role="outer"/>
    <member type="relation" ref="1263863" role="outer"/>
    <member type="relation" ref="1263868" role="outer"/>
    <member type="relation" ref="1628087" role="outer"/>
    <tag k="ISO3166-1" v="FR"/>
    <tag k="TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:Class" v="Area"/>
    <tag k="TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:LCLversion" v="8.00"/>
    <tag k="TMC:cid_58:tabcd_1:LocationCode" v="2"/>
    <tag k="admin_level" v="2"/>
    <tag k="currency" v="EUR"/>
    <tag k="flag" v="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/c/c3/Flag_of_France.svg"/>
    <tag k="land_area" v="administrative"/>

...... and so on ......
```

How to get a set of lng/lat (WKT or GEOJson) of the territory (countries and cities only) by their name?

Answer (score 3):

I would use the area feature of the Overpass API in order to achieve this goal.

```
[out:json];
area
   ["name"="France"]
   ["boundary"="administrative"]
   ["admin_level"="2"];
(._;(pivot:);>;);
out body qt;
```

Lines 2-5 are selecting the correct area.

Line 6 creates an union consisting of:

- the area itself
- the pivot element of this area (the relationship/way/... from which this area was generated)
- the ways/nodes referenced by the pivot element

Line 7 just prints out the results. The qt parameter is just a performance optimization and not necessary (http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#order_attribute)

By setting admin_level to 2 you can make sure, that you will only get national borders.
You will need to adapt this value in order to get different types of boundaries. A list of the meaning of admin_level's values can be found at http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Admin_level#admin_level.

By the way:
Areas are created by the Overpass-API server and are not part of the original OpenStreetMap database. Internally, the Overpass server is doing exactly what scai wrote: It is gathering together the data from relationships. (see wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Areas)

Comment: I'm getting ERROR 400: Bad Request with this query, looks like `(._;(pivot:);>;);` doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Where did you read about this `coverage=polygon` tag you specified in your first query? There is no such [tag](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tags) and therefore the query returns no results. You are mainly interested in the [boundary=administrative](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:boundary=administrative) and [admin_level=2](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Key:admin_level#admin_level) tags.

Your second query returns [relation 11980](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/relation/11980). As you can see in your XML output it contains other *members* with the role *outer*, for example [relation 1362232](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/relation/1362232). This is the relation for *France métropolitaine* and also contains other members with the role *outer*, for example [relation 90162](http://www.openstreetmap.org/browse/relation/90162). This relation now finally defines a part of the country border at the English channel. It contains several *ways* as member which in turn are just a list of *nodes* (and possibly some tags). Every node has a coordinate and thus all nodes together define the polygon for France.

If you are not yet familiar with *relations*, *ways* and *nodes* then start reading about OSM's [elements](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements). Relations are not actually some type of polygons but contain other elements such as other relations, ways or nodes which in turn can define a polygon, or something else depending on the *tags*.

As a consequence you may have to run further queries for your relation members, depending on the output (note that not every country relation looks the same, OSM is very flexible here). [Overpass API](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API) is also capable of *recursive* queries which you can use to retrieve all relation members, see the [Overpass API language guide](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Language_Guide#Also_relations_on_relations) for further information.

Answer (score 2):

```
relation
    //Name of country with native language
    // Use ["name:en"="France"] for english
    ["name"="France"]
    [boundary=administrative]
    [admin_level=2];

(._;>;);

out body qt;
```

It will return you `Polygons`, `Lines` and `Points`, so filter features by type, when import to GIS.